# React-redux: Get deviceid and device info without npm

Tags: react-redux, react-native, deviceid

Can I get device-id and device-info without this **react-native-device-info** in react-native; like we get location info in device.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Asking question format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: To obtain device information, you'll need to tap into the native code (Swift/Objective-C / Java). You can either write your own implementation or use a library (like the one you've mentioned). You cannot get such information through JavaScript alone.

Comment: @Momin oops thanks for your effort....

Answer (score 0):

You can get device info by using the RN 'Platform' package. You can't get device ID though, you would need to bridge API to Javascript as a Native Module.

**Example for getting device info (exkl. device ID):**

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

_getOS() {
  return Platform.OS 
}

_getOSVersion() {
  return Platform.Version
}
```